# How do I test iPhone 'touch event' on PC

Tags: ios, touch-event

I want to test on iPhone/iPod touch.

Comment: Please be more precise in your question. What exactly do you want to test where?

Answer (score 2):

To develop or test applications for the iPhone, you need the Apple iPhone SDK (http://developer.apple.com/iphone/) which requires a Mac.

Comment: I think he's referring to testing touch events on a website via Safari, but your answer still works in that case.  He just needs to run the iPhone Simulator and Mobile Safari within the simulator.